# Rooting HP Slate 21 all in one with built in Android Jelly bean 4.2.2

Tags: rooting

Any ideas on how to root a HP Slate 21 all in one with Android Jelly bean 4.2.2? I am going crazy trying to find a solution for this.

Comment: You may want to look into the methods used to root other recent HP Android tablets, like the [method for the Slate 7](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2422353). However, be very careful! I don't recommend using untested methods on your device.

Comment: The method to root slate 7 is done via micro usb to the PC. The HP Slate 21 all in one has no ports to connect to a PC. Is there a method to install a APK and root the HP Slate 21?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I've ever seen a device that you can root with just an APK. Although I wouldn't completely dismiss the possibility. **Also** in the case of the Slate 21, you may be able to use ADB over Wifi instead of USB.

Comment: In most cases, root permission is required to use ADB over wifi. Any other solution?

Comment: Well then.... I'm stumped.

Comment: I have found this link to enter recovery mode in the HP Slate 21. http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c03915683&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&product=5381346

Comment: Is there any Android Jelly Bean 4.2.2 image (rooted) that I can use on a SD Card and use the above link and overwrite the default Android image provided by HP Slate 21 all in one?

Comment: Probably not. And if there was, there would probably be problems flashing it (as it would be unsigned) with the default Recovery Mode. A custom recovery would most likely be necessary to flash such a system image.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a to a USB cable that works.
Adb works
And flash boot
There is a adb fingerprint for drivers at hp3 forum.

Unlocking boot loader also no problem.
Root don't work with the normal stuff,
And the Chinese program's also failed.
Wait for a tegra4 like version hope will come soon,
Think its hacked until Christmas.

Comment: I bought a to a USB cable and connected it to my HP Slate 21 and my MAC Mini (Lion). Adb does not detect any device. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

First activate USB debugging by tapping 7 times on Settings → About Tablet → Build Number.

Then connect the tablet to the PC via the side USB port.

For PC:

1. Edit the USB fingerprint for drivers (refer HP help forum and questions such as how-to adb with slate 21). Use PC as Macs won't work unless they get a new kernel update like Linux (since the driver is in Linux kernel 3.9).
2. Install the driver manually through "Update driver" in Device Manager as auto install of drivers doesn't work.

Also you will need the other stuff from the Android SDK, most importantly the new ADB platform-tools (Version 1.0.32).

This device is too new, so there is no driver and it is unsupported by HP.

Comment: Franny, your answer stops at the crucial point. You only describe how to get ADB working (some links and explanations on the single steps, like how to "adapt the driver handish", would be useful here). But the question was how to *root* the device, and that part is entirely missing. Could you please [edit] your question to include this?

Answer (score 0):

Give [Cydia Impactor](http://www.cydiaimpactor.com/) a try - it works on the tnote 7 and HP Slate 8.